# Prove that the differential map is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $D \in L(P(R), P(R))$ is such that $deg D p = (deg p) - 1$ for every non constant polynomial $p \in P(R)$. Prove that D is surjective (using only the fact that D decreases the degree of p by one, not using the formula for the differentiation of a polynomial).

I was going to stay, suppose $p \in P_m(F)$ then $deg D p = m -1$, which is always greater than or equal to zero since we know p is not a constant polynomial. since dim p > dim D p, then the linear map must be surjective.

The theorem I used states that: Suppose V and W are finite dimensional vector spaces such that dim V < dim W. Then no linear map from V to W is surjective.

I'm not sure if I can negate the theorem like that but I can't think of another way to do the proof. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$  Let $p\in P(R)$, so $p\in P_{m}(R)$ for some $m\ge0$.

Now use that $D:P_{m+1}(R)\rightarrow P_{m}(R)$ with $\text{rank}(D)+\text{nullity}(D)=\dim(P_{m+1}(R))=m+2$.

Comment: So using this I would get that $nullD = 1$, correct? But what does that tell me? If $nullD = {0}$ I could say that D is injective, but that doesn't tell me anything about it being surjective?

Comment: If you are allowed to use the fact that nullity(D)=1 (since only constant functions have derivative 0), then you can use this to solve for rank(D).